# How to get the data permanently recieved by POST method in a file?

Tags: php, html

Good day experts!!!

In the code below, the copy.php file will create another php base on input values and will send input values on the newly created php file. On the same page, at first the codes works well but if I open the newly created php file directly, it will give an error  PHP Warning:  Undefined array key "subject/etc.......). How do I put the values permanently on the post section of the newly created file replacing the post code?

Here's my code below:

copy.php

```
<?php
$file = 'data.php';
$newfile = $_POST["newFileName"].'.php';

if (!copy($file, $newfile)) {
    echo "failed to copy";
}else {
    echo "<center><form action='$newfile' method='post'>

Name of the exam: <br><input type='text' name='subject' required><br><br>
Instruction: <br><input type='text' name='instruction' required><br><br>
Questions:<br>
<input type='text' name='new_1'><br>
<input type='text' name='new_2'><br>
<input type='text' name='new_3'><br>
<input type='text' name='new_4'><br>
<input type='text' name='new_5'><br><br>

<input type='submit' value='Create Quiz'>
</form></center>";
}
?>
```

newfile.php

```
<?php
$subject=$_POST['subject'];
$instruction=$_POST['instruction'];
$q1=$_POST['new_1'];
$q2=$_POST['new_2'];
$q3=$_POST['new_3'];
$q4=$_POST['new_4'];
$q5=$_POST['new_5'];

echo 
"<form action='' method='post' onsubmit='alert('SUBMITTED SUCCESFULLY!')'>
Name: <input type='text' name='NAME' required><br><br>
$subject <br><br>
$instruction <br><br>
<input type='text' name='1' required> $q1 <br>
<input type='text' name='2' required> $q2 <br>
<input type='text' name='3' required> $q3 <br>
<input type='text' name='4' required> $q4 <br>
<input type='text' name='5' required> $q5 <br><br>
<input type='submit' value='submit' onclick='return Confirm();'>
</form>";
?>
```

Comment: You might want to validate the contents of `$_POST["newFileName"]` before creating a file with whatever that string contains. As it stands anyone using the form can potentially overwrite any file on the server, including the `copy.php` file, effectively breaking the whole application. Also, even though you are appending `.php` to the input string, someone could submit `/an/absolute/path/to/a/critical/file%00` and depending on your version of PHP this would prevent the suffix extension from even working, so the critical file would be overwritten with your form. Security is hard with PHP 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't open newfile.php directely and have the answers.
The copy file call newfile with the form. newfile expect to receive POST datas. If you open directly newfile, you don't have POST data because no datas where sent.

What you can do :
In copy PHP start a session (`session_start()`) and give a name to the submit button  : `<input type='submit' value='Create Quiz' name='subForm'>`

In newfile.php you can have something like that :

```
<?php
session_start();
if(isset($_POST['subForm'])){
$_SESSION['copyForm'] = serialize($_POST);
}
$myForm = unserialize($_SESSION['copyForm']);
$subject=$myForm['subject'];
$instruction=$myForm['instruction'];
$q1=$myForm['new_1'];
$q2=$myForm['new_2'];
$q3=$myForm['new_3'];
$q4=$myForm['new_4'];
$q5=$myForm['new_5'];

echo 
"<form action='' method='post' onsubmit='alert('SUBMITTED SUCCESFULLY!')'>
Name: <input type='text' name='NAME' required><br><br>
$subject <br><br>
$instruction <br><br>
<input type='text' name='1' required> $q1 <br>
<input type='text' name='2' required> $q2 <br>
<input type='text' name='3' required> $q3 <br>
<input type='text' name='4' required> $q4 <br>
<input type='text' name='5' required> $q5 <br><br>
<input type='submit' value='submit' onclick='return Confirm();'>
</form>";
?>
```

Comment: Thanks you sir. I will try to do your suggestion. I'll inform you about the results.

Comment: My God! It worked!! Thank you so much sir. Now I can continue creating a quiz system on out school local network. I will include you in my credits. Once again, thank you sir.